# The order of collision1~2 objects from contact sensor

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-sensor, contact, collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

From contact sensor, we can get contact objects (gazebo::physics::Contact).

The contact object includes followings.

```
std::string     collision1
    Name of the first collision object.
 
std::string     collision2
    Name of the second collision object.
```

How does Gazebo decide the order ?

And, how about following?
Assumption:

```
(1) There is a contact between link_1 and link_2, 
(2) link_1 has contact sensor.
```

Among the resulted contact objects from sensor, if the objects' elements are like following,

```
 (1) collision1 specifies link_1
 (2) collision2 specifies link_2
```

wrench(i).body_1_force in those objects are forces from link_2 to link_1.
Am I right?

The '1,2' things make me really confused. I really need help.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/893/the-order-of-collision1%7E2-objects-from-contact-sensor/) by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The order of reported collisions is non-deterministic.

The wrenches reported by a contact sensor are the forces between the two links in contact.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0